# Filtering through Javascript 2d array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, 2d

i have a 2d array like this

```
 var items = [['alex',2],['alex',4],['alex',6],['jhon',11],['jhon',13]];
```

But in html i want to render this array like

```
**Names**   **Numbers**

  alex   => 2,4,6
  jhon   => 11,13
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried already.

Comment: [Array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: the right term is *grouping*.

Comment: I am not much expert in JavaScript  2d array ..i ca't figure it out that how can i do this i am trying from last 2 hours..i googled  and i just find remove duplicates but don't know how to apply that

Comment: Please give a example..Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` to return object and then `Object.keys()` and `forEach` loop to add to HTML

```js
var items = [['alex',2],['alex',4],['alex',6],['jhon',11],['jhon',13]];
var result = items.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e[0]] = (r[e[0]] || []).concat(e[1]);
  return r;
}, {});

var rows = '';
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(e) {
  rows += '<tr><td>' + e + '</td><td>' + result[e].join(',') + '</td></tr>';
});

document.querySelector('table tbody').innerHTML += rows;
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Names</td><td>Numbers</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much..perfect..this is what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reduce and array grouping I propose a jQuery approach (this is not the best solution but only a different point of view):

```js
$(function () {
  var items = [['alex',2],['alex',4],['alex',6],['jhon',11],['jhon',13]];
  $.each(items, function(indexInArray, value) {
    var cellIfExist = $('#result').find('td:contains(' + value[0] + ')');
    if (cellIfExist.length > 0) {
      cellIfExist.next().text(cellIfExist.next().text() + ', ' + value[1]);
    } else {
      $('#result').append('<tr><td>' + value[0] + '</td><td>' + value[1] + '</td></tr>')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<table id="result">
    <tr>
        <td>**Names**</td>
        <td>**Numbers**</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks  i needed jquery version :)

Answer (score 0):

well the old-school way is probably to iterate over the array and while doing so build an object that's pretty much like an associative array.

```
 var items = [['alex',2],['alex',4],['alex',6],['jhon',11],['jhon',13]];
 var group = { }

 for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var pair = items[i];
    if(group[pair[0]]) {
    group[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
  }
 else {
    group[pair[0]] = [pair[1]];
  }
}
```

"group" is then your grouped object. Iterate over it using a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `Array.forEach` function:

```js
var items = [['alex',2],['alex',4],['alex',6],['jhon',11],['jhon',13]],
    names = {};
items.forEach(function (arr) {
    (names[arr[0]])? names[arr[0]].push(arr[1]) : (names[arr[0]] = [arr[1]]);
});
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(names, 0, 4));
```